# Using datepicker in codeigniter when javascript is disabled

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter, datepicker

How to get DatePicker in Codeigniter view when javascript is disabled?

Comment: In html5 data type input are available ,chk this linkhttp://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_form_input_types.asp

Comment: Thnx, but I have to use firefox and it doesnt support that

Comment: i think this may be the only way that we can use datepicker without using JS

Comment: Can you use CI Calendar?  http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/calendar.html

Comment: I tried that but I am getting only a calender displayed...is there any way to select a date from it?  Thnx

Answer (score 1):

You cant. Datepickers work with Javascript. Best you can do is to leave a message by the datepicker div to tell the user to enable Javascript to use the Datepicker.

Comment: The answer is correct, except that I'd omit the message and just allow to enter dates with a regular input field. Users don't disable JavaScript inadvertently. Not sure though whether CodeIgniter presents any particular difficulty for this.